# How to get child element values connected and include spaces?

Tags: jquery

I have this div in my HTML page:

```
<div id="" class="ellipsize-text">
   <h4>Sherlock</h4>
   <span>S2:E2</span>
   <span>The Hounds of Baskerville</span>
</div>
```

I want to harvest the full title and end up with this:

**Sherlock S2:E2 The Hounds of Baskerville**

My first stab at this was to call `$(".video-title").first()[0].innerText`, which produces **SherlockS2:E2The Hounds of Baskerville**. Notice how the segments are crammed together with no spaces. I then tried traversing children and parsing pieces out, but I must be doing something wrong and can't seem to traverse it correctly.

What is the most efficient way (or at least simplest) to harvest that inner html (using jQuery) to produce my desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text contents. Or if you need space separated text content of child elements then iterate over child nodes and generate the content.

```js
console.log(
  $('.ellipsize-text').text().trim()
)

// or with space

console.log(
  $('.ellipsize-text')
  // get all child nodes
  .contents()
  // iterate over the child nodes
  .map(function() {
    // return the text content of the element
    return $(this).text().trim();
  })
  // get the result as an array from the jQuery object
  .get()
  // join the array strings with a single space
  .join(' ')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="" class="ellipsize-text">
  <h4>Sherlock</h4>
  <span>S2:E2</span>
  <span>The Hounds of Baskerville</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it for *each* `div` with a given class (`ellipsize-text` in your HTML):

```
$(".ellipsize-text").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).children().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(" "));
});
```

We use `children` to get all the children of the `div`, then `map` to get their text, `get` to get an array (instead of jQuery object), and `join(" ")` to add them together with spaces.

Live copy:

```js
$(".ellipsize-text").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).children().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(" "));
});
```

```html
<div id="" class="ellipsize-text">
   <h4>Sherlock</h4>
   <span>S2:E2</span>
   <span>The Hounds of Baskerville</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```